# Linq Select many where property x exists in externalList

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Poor wording I know, so I will be clear here..

I have

```
List<int> relevantIDs; //self explanitory
```

Now I am trying to select a list of objects from the database where their IDs exist within the list above... I cant seem to figure out the linq...

```
dbContext.objs.where(x => x.id ....).toList();
//I cant figure out the .... i was thinking there was an "in" but got no where...
```

can someone point me to an article or provide me a sample that will accomplish what I need. The list would be too big to just retrieve them all then filter down.... and hitting the database repeatedly would be not optimal in this case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to find the IDs from the database that are contained *within* your collection of "relevant IDs", so this should work:

```
dbContext.objs.Where(x => relevantIDs.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `Contains`

```
dbContext.objs.Where(x => relevantIDs.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```

This will be translated as `IN` clause into `SQL`.